# How can I render a model on top of another model regardless of their relative Z positions?

Tags: xna, models

I was wondering if there's any way to render models over other 3D models regardless of their relative positions? Kind of like how it works in 2D graphics, you set a render order and it renders them based on that instead of taking the depth and figuring out which is in front of which.

Comment: Check out z-buffers

Comment: If you disable depth testing then the models will be rendered in the order you draw them, just like in 2D.

Comment: And with the depth testing turned off the 3D model being rendered will be all sorts of ugly because it will draw all over itself.  Is there some reason that you cannot properly position the models in 3D space like mother nature intended?

Answer (score 2):

Normally when we render 3D graphics, we make use of a [depth buffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb976071.aspx) to achieve the proper visual appearance of solid objects in relation to each other regardless of the rendering order of said objects.

If, as in your case, you *do not* want this behavior, simply disable it somewhere in your initialization code. Do this by creating a new [state object that controls the depth and stencil buffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.depthstencilstate.aspx) and setting the [appropriate member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.depthstencilstate.depthbufferenable.aspx) to `false`, then assign your state object to the graphics device[enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice.aspx):

```
var state = new DepthStencilState();
state.DepthBufferEnable = false;

GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = state;
```

After the `GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = state` expression, objects will fully draw in the order in which you submit them for rendering, allowing you to draw objects over others regardless of their actual position in the world.

If you only want to do this for some subset of your objects, draw the world normally first, then set the depth-stencil state accordingly (make sure to reset it to a one that enables the depth buffer before you draw again for the next frame, and also make sure that you always create the state objects in your initialization code -- don't create them every frame, as that is expensive and wasteful).

Comment: But you should be aware that for example your model will be also drawn without depth buffer. So triangles further from you may override those which are closer. It depends on draw-order. You may get something like this: http://tomdalling.com/wp-content/uploads/depth-buffer-disabled.png

Comment: Very true. A simple way to try to combat that is to *clear* the depth buffer between each object, rather than disable altogether. But that isn't without its own problems, either.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a two pass rendering. First pass you render the models that you want in the back. Then in the second pass instead of clearing the screen to redraw the frame, you only render the objects that you want to draw over the other models. That way the models in the second pass will draw over whatever was previously drawn.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to illeyezur's answer - to make this work, you will also need to clear the depth buffer in between drawing the two objects. This will let you keep depth testing enabled, so objects don't draw all over themselves and look awful, but will make sure that the object drawn second will always win in a depth test against the object drawn first.

So the procedure is:

1. Draw object you want to always appear behind.
2. Clear depthbuffer to `1` (the maximum depth value).
3. Draw second object, which will always appear on top.

Here, depth testing should be enabled throughout.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable the depth buffer, you should use it well. Draw the stuff in the front, so those pixels behind don't need to be drawn.